# setting SPNEGO credentials in Jersey client

Tags: jersey, spnego

I have some REST services created using Jersey which use SPENGO for authentication.  I am creating acceptance tests using the Jersey client.  I am wondering how to use the Jersey client to set the SPENGO headers. I looked into filters but don't really understand it.  If somebody could supply a code example, it would be much appreciated.